How to parameterize a generic function parameter?
For example I have a generic static method in a class and want to get its parameter type given the generic argument:
class Model{
    id = 0;
    title = 'test';
}

class Child extends Model{
    child = true;
}

class Foo {

    static func<T extends Model>(a: Omit<T, 'id'>): number{
        return 0;
    }

}

type p = Parameters<typeof Foo['func']>[0] // how to get Child here?

Any way to achieve that? Any proper syntax?
Playground

Please see Is it OK to make a clarifying edit to a question if it will invalidate existing answers?

Instead of using Foo['func'], use Foo.func. The dot notation supports specifying a generic type, whereas the bracket notation does not.
type p = Parameters<typeof Foo.func<Child>>[0]


while this answer seems to be correct i cant use it since it gives:
Cannot access 'T.get' because 'T' is a type, but not a namespace. Did you mean to retrieve the type of the property 'get' in 'T' with 'T["get"]'?(2713)

I'm not seeing where you call T["get"] in your question.  Do you need to update the question with additional requirements?

Unfortunately, the question has been significantly altered. In fact, the original question did not focus on this problem (there OP only wanted to pass the type to the function what called, and this is possible with dot notation - as my answer mentioned). Here (after OP modification), the problem is that a generic type T needs to reference the func, and in this case, only bracket notation can be used. However, this way, it cannot pass a type to the function (and here I would wonder why a type should even be passed to func).

Actually, the OP should have opened a new question that better addresses the solution to the error message they received.
